# How to use condition in many to many relationship laravel?

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have three model Company, User, Project

```
companies:
id, name
```

```
users: 
id, name
```

```
projects: 
id, title, company_id
```

Pivot table

```
project_members: 
id, user_id, project_id
```

**users** and **projects** relationship is many to many.
How do I get all **Projects** with special user_id joined in Project or not.

Here is my code get list Projects user does not join but it was not expected:

```
$project = Project::with(['company', 'users'])
               ->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($user) {
                   $query->where('id', '!=', $user->id);
               });
```

I hope you could help me and explain how to use **with**, **whereHas** in Laravel.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you asking how to create a relationship between projects and users or how to access the relationship?

Comment: I have relationships of users and projects. Now i want to get list Project by condtions of User. 
Ex: get list projects if user joined project or not.

Comment: Apologies, I'm having a tough time figuring out what you want. According to your edit do you want to get a list of projects that don't have a certain user?

Comment: Yes. I want to get list of projects that don't have user.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project::with(['users' => function($q)]) loads all projects and the users that satisfies the subquery. In this case all projects and the user with the selected id if exists

And Project::whereHas('users', function($q) {}) loads only the projects that satisfies the users subquery, in your case: projects where are assigned to the user with the selected id